# iOS - Handling Multiple Checkboxes

Tags: ios, objective-c, checkbox, uibutton

I need to use checkboxes (instead of UISwitch), as eventually these are going to be printed onto a sheet. I'm using the following code to initialize my check box

```
checkbox1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 226.5, 134, 20)];
[checkbox1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[checkbox1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[checkbox1 addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addSubview:checkbox1];
```

and the following code to handle the switch

```
-(void)checkboxSelected:(id)sender {

if([checkbox1 isSelected]==YES) {
    [checkbox1 setSelected:NO];
} else {
    [checkbox1 setSelected:YES];
}
```

All this works perfectly fine . . .  when I'm dealing with 1 checkbox  . . . but if I want to have lets say 10 checkboxes on the same page - Do i need to create 10 separate methods ?

It just seems wasteful . . ..  is there a better way to acheive this ?

Thank you for all your help

Comment: You could create your own control (custom class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have the same method for all checkboxes. Sender parameter in your checkboxSelected method is the UIButton that triggered the action, so it will be tapped checkbox in your case:

```
-(void)checkboxSelected:(UIButton*)sender {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
```

Comment: There is Not necessary to set tag of button while we create a button like as par above question.? with you answer.?

Comment: Thank you: this is actually perfect, it works! but could you explain it a little bit so I can accept your answer? - whats happening at `sender.selected = !sender.selected` ?

Comment: @NitinGohel, you don't need tag if you just want to change selected state. But you may need it when you will retrieve selected states later for future processing, that may depend on the structure of your data

Comment: yes that i thinking bcz in question use set imaeg of check unchecked so i think it's better to use tag and set also image of button as par selected state in to **-(void)checkboxSelected:(UIButton*)sender**

Comment: @TaskinulHaque, as I explained in answer sender parameter is the button that was tapped to trigger method call, then sender.selected = !sender.selected simply changes selected value to opposite - YES to NO and vice versa.

Comment: -editthank you again : @NitinGohel I apologize I didn't get a chance to upvote your answer it to would have been useful for others I'm sure

Comment: ok no prob main think is your issue was solve. i put my answer again and nice work @TaskinulHaque

Answer (score 1):

you have to manage evey Button check Box withing a single Method by using tag:-

Lat say you crating 10 Buttong with ForLoop

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
checkbox1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 226.5, 134, 20)];
[checkbox1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[checkbox1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
checkbox1.tag=i;
[checkbox1 setSelected:NO];
[checkbox1 addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addSubview:checkbox1];
}

-(void)checkboxSelected:(UIButton*)sender {
     UIButton *btnPly = (UIButton *)sender;
    if([btnPly isSelected]==YES) {
        [btnPly setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnPly setSelected:NO];
    } else {
        [btnPly setSelected:YES];
        [btnPly setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I think my spelling errors could have caused some confusion  . . . . could you look at the question again ? what if the buttons need to be positioned on different CG-coordinates ?

Comment: this above method set 10 sepreated check box of button but about CG-cordinates position you need to set it's frame as par you need in to forLoop

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
HTN = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 226.5, 134, 20)];
[HTN setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[HTN setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
HTN.tag=i;
[HTN addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxSelect:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addSubview:checkbox1];
}
```

and to check whether selected or not

```
-(void)checkboxSelect:(UIButton*)sender {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
```